# DirectoryIndex in .htaccess giving internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two index files and i want both to be there. I wrote `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` in my `.htaccess` file. This is the only line in my .htaccess file and when i opened site browser is giving error 500.

Comment: read your apache error.log file

Comment: where this file can be found? I am hosting my site on a external server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server probably hasn't set `AllowOverride Indexes`.  If they haven't then `DirectoryIndex` in an .htaccess file isn't allowed, and you get 500 when you try.

Some options:

1. See if the web provider will grant `AllowOverride Indexes` in your URL space.
2. Ask what values of DirectoryIndex they do allow (maybe index.php, index.cgi, etc.) and use one of those instead.
3. Use a RewriteRule (if they allow that :| ), for example:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^$  index.php
   ```